# distinct values in a Linq to sql string.Join()

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table which contains the schedule for a class. it contains the teacherid and name, datetime of the class and the course for that specific time.

```
teacherid    teachername    startdate         coursename
1            john           9/1/2014 10:00    math
2            john           9/2/2014 10:00    math
3            jane           9/3/2014 10:00    english
4            john           9/4/2014 10:00    french
5            jack           9/5/2014 10:00    history
6            jane           9/6/2014 10:00    math
```

I want to write a linq to sql query which returns which teacher gives which courses, as such:

```
Teachername    courses
john           math, french
jane           english, math
jack           history
```

I've gotten as far as the following

```
var _classes = from _c in dbContext.classes                           
                       where _c.StartDate < System.DateTime.Now
                       group _c by new
                       {
                           _c.TeacherId,
                           _c.TeacherName,
                           _c.CourseName
                       } into g
                       select new
                       {
                           g.Key.TeacherName,
                           courses = string.Join(",", from i in g select i.CourseName)
                       };
```

but i'm getting the following output

```
Teachername    courses
john           math, math, french
jane           english, math
jack           history
```

so john is getting the math value twice. 
how do I make the string.Join function use distinct values?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no query syntax for `distinct` so you should change to method syntax:

```
courses = string.Join(",", g.Select(i => i.CourseName).Distinct())
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `Distinct` to your select clause in `String.Join` like:

```
courses = string.Join(",", (from i in g select i.CourseName).Distinct())
```

Or use method Syntax for select as well like:

```
courses = string.Join(",", (g.Select(i=> i.CourseName).Distinct())
```